# PHP login allow email and username

Tags: php, html, mysql, login-script

I have had a little help making this really simple PHP login script. It all works perfectly but I keep putting my email in the username field. I'm not really sure how to convert this code to do that as I had help writing this and the rest of the files!
I have tried to look at other forums on this and other people's questions but none of the replies commented on stack or other sites seems to work for my code.

thanks!

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once '../config.php';

// var_dump($_POST);
// exit();

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);


$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '". $username ."' AND password = '". $password ."'" ;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    header('Location: ../dashboard/index');
} else {
    header('Location: ../index.php?message=Username address or password is incorrect');
}

?>
```

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username = '". $username ."'  OR email= '". $username ."') AND password = '". $password ."'" ;` at least i think thats what your asking

Comment: Why do you set the session twice? Seems somewhat redundant, don't you think?

Comment: Legend! Works a treat, many thanks!

Comment: Qirel, What would you recommend I do?

Comment: Hash your users passwords. Use `$_SESSION['username'] = $username` or `$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];` they are the same. Use `exit()` after your `header` call. You also should use parameterized queries over escaping.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
session_start();


//Yes it is true 


include_once '../config.php';
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);

//prepared approach!
$query = $con -> prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE (username = ? or email = ?) AND password = ? ");
$query->bind_param('sss',$username,$username,$password);
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();
if($query->num_rows>0){
    //therefore the USER exists!!!!!

    //Please dont fetch the same username again because it alreadmatched here.
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('Location: ../dashboard/index');

}else{
    header('Location: ../index.php?message=Username address or password is incorrect');
}
```